# Sending ASCII instead of string

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I am tring to send data to the com port, but the device i am talking to only takes ASCII or HEX and what i am sending is string..  How can i change this to send ASCII or Hex instead?

```
hCommFile: THandle;
```

on the create..

```
 hCommFile := CreateFile(PChar('COM1'),
                          GENERIC_READ,
                          0,
                          nil,
                          OPEN_EXISTING,
                          FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                          0);
```

Sending Data

```
{****************************************************************************}
procedure TForm4.WriteString(sToSend:string);
//While in THIS program, we only write stings,
//  this procedure is perfectly capable of sending a
//  "string" consisting of a single character.
var NumberWritten : dWord;
  //The type of NumberWritten is problematic... some
  //posts online say use dWord, others say use longint.
  //Perhaps it is a matter of what version of Windows
  //   and/or Delphi you have? For XP + Delphi 4, dWord is right.
begin
if WriteFile(hCommFile,
               PChar(sToSend)^,
               Length(sToSend),
               NumberWritten,
               nil)=false then
      showmessage('Unable to send');
end;//WriteString
```

Comment: What to you mean by hex?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan as in 'LOFF' in hex would be 4c 4f 46 46  The device would take either.

Comment: That makes no sense to me.

Comment: some call it base 16 if that helps

Comment: I understand what hex is quite clearly. I don't see its relevance here. I wonder why you use GENERIC_READ.

Comment: The reason is the device will accept ANSII or HEX commands.. I Used Generic_Read cause i set it up to to read by default.

Comment: Oh, you edited one of your comments. FWIW there is no hex at the comms level. Just ASCII. You might write the data as hex or decimal or binary but you are just sending ASCII encoded text. Remember that hexadecimal is simply a representation of a value.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Some RS-232 protocols are binary and not ASCII, or sometimes combine data types.  More accurate to say that at the comms level there are only bytes, I think.  ASCII is one interpretation of those bytes, but it is not always the intended interpretation.  Certainly I've seen protocols where the decimal value "127" would be sent as two bytes in the string `"7F"` and some where it would be sent as a single byte of `&H7F`.  Although it is not relevant here, it's important to make the distinction.

Comment: @J... It would be pretty messed up to encode ASCII 127 using base 16. What I've been driving at here is that a lot of people seem to struggle to understand that hex is just a way of representing a value. So decimal 127, hex 7f and binary 01111111 are all different representation of the same value.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Perhaps messed up, yes, but it is surprisingly common in clear text protocols.  Not typically to encode ASCII, mind, but to encode numeric values in command or response packets.  Many byte values, when sent as ASCII, are control characters and cause problems when using standard terminals.  Older devices usually send numeric values as strings - `"127"` takes three bytes, `"7F"` takes two bytes, and `&H7F` takes only one byte (with the caveat that it is not human-readable, being the DEL character). Many protocols, when sending numeric data, will do so using ascii represented hex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing

```
procedure TForm4.WriteString(sToSend:string);
```

to

```
procedure TForm4.WriteString(const sToSend:ansistring);
```

and

```
PChar(sToSend)^,
```

to

```
PAnsiChar(sToSend)^,
```

should work...

Your problem is that XE2 uses UniCode for strings (2 bytes per character), so you need to convert the string to send into a 1 byte per character format. The easiest way to do that is to declare the parameter as AnsiString (the old STRING type), and let the compiler do all the hocus pocus for you behind the scenes.

Comment: So if currently i do a `WriteSTring(SomeString)`   I now have to change this to `WriteSTring(someAnsisString)` along with the change above..or can i keep it as `WriteString(SomeString)`  thanks

Comment: You can keep your code as-is. The compiler will convert your SomeString (which is a UnicodeString in XE2) to an AnsiString for you, before passing it along to the procedure. Beware, though, that you may have problems with certain internation characters, but if you stick to plain old ASCII you'll have no problems...

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it has solved your problem. As for your reading from the device, if you post a new question, we can take a stab at it there...

Comment: Do be aware that implicitly converting UTF-16 text to ANSI leads to warning W1058: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/W1058_Implicit_string_cast_with_potential_data_loss_from_'%25s'_to_'%25s'_(Delphi)

Answer (score 2):

Delphi strings have never been ASCII encoded. Prior to Delphi 2009, Delphi used 8bit ANSI encoded strings. Modern versions use 16bit UTF-16 encoded strings instead. You are sending UTF-16 encoded text where 8bit ASCII is expected. What's more, because UTF-16 character elements are two bytes wide, and `Length()` returns the number of characters not the number of bytes, you are only sending half of your wrongly-encoded string to the comm port.

Use the `SysUtils.TEncoding` class to convert a UTF-16 encoded string to an 8bit ASCII encoded byte array:

```
bytes := TEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
```

Your use of this might look like this:

```
procedure WriteString(const str: string);
var
  bytes: TBytes;
  BytesWritten: DWORD;
begin
  bytes := TEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);
  if not WriteFile(hCommFile, Pointer(bytes)^,
    Length(bytes), BytesWritten, nil) then
    // handle error
end;
```

Your code is implemented as a method in a GUI form. This feels like the wrong place for it. A low-level wrapper class would give you better encapsulation and reusability.